# htaccess not working properly- 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess not working , apache configuration , i install apache,php7,mysql AS seprate, i enable mod_rewrite, but when in htaccess i type  it give me 500 internal server error

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Turn on Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite rule

#RewriteRule ^detail detail.php [NC,L]

# NC makes the rule non case sensitive
# L  makes the last rule that specific condition will match

# Rewrite For detail.php?id=1

RewriteRule ^detail/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) detail.php?id=$1 [NC,L]


# Rewrite For detail.php?id=1&title=title

RewriteRule ^detail/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) detail.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]


<IfModule>
```

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: Another problem in your code is that /detail.php is rewriting back to itself causing loop error 500, try adding a $ to the pattern. "^detail$

Comment: @Starkeen that line is commented out (or hopefully in production it is as well)..

Comment: So does the answer below resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The trailing `<Ifmodule>` should be `</Ifmodule>`. As is that is opening a second block.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on
# Rewrite rule
#RewriteRule ^detail detail.php [NC,L]
# NC makes the rule non case sensitive
# L  makes the last rule that specific condition will match
# Rewrite For detail.php?id=1
RewriteRule ^detail/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) detail.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
# Rewrite For detail.php?id=1&title=title
RewriteRule ^detail/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) detail.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: really now, some explanation goes a long way .. why spell `</Ifmodule>` and then differently in the code: `</IfModule>` - exact pairing in both? - you created 2 pairs, each pair spelled the same in a set, but the pairs are not the same, `M` and `m`.

Comment: @argon What are you talking about?? Please read my answer, look at the code, and look at the OPs code.

Comment: look at the spelling - in terms of case sensitivity ;)

Comment: @argon Still no idea what you are talking about, maybe your browser is not rendering correctly (here's a demonstration, https://3v4l.org/9X2UE (these are copy any pasted from the code) and for proof that it wouldn't work if the cases were different https://3v4l.org/rIgbZ) Maybe you are referring to the context sentence rather than the actual code?

Comment: You are right, my browser is dumb, or I am dumber than my browser, because it is as clear as the nose on my face, the caps is in red (in code) and non-caps in the reference above the code .. anyway, bygones :)